# Convergent Laurent series for a function outside region of convergence of respective Tayor series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, laurent-series

Take the function

$$
f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$

defined on the complex plane.

We can write a Taylor expansion about $z = 0$ for $f$, which turns out to be:

$$
f(z) = -1 - 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n
$$

with region of convergence $|z| < 1$.

Now, let's say I wanted an Laurent series for this function, still around $z = 0$, but this time for the region $|z| > 1$. How would I go about this?

I have tried applying the definition of the Laurent series, but as far as I can tell, it only applies for an expansion around a pole, and $z = 0$ is not a pole of $f$.

The result for the Laurent expansion about $z = 0$ in this region, which I am trying to reach, is

$$
f(z) = 1 + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{-n}
$$

but I have absolutely no clue how to get there.

Comment: One way could be $f(z)=1-\frac{2}{z-1}=1-\frac{2}{z}\frac{1}{1-1/z}$. Then use that for $|x|<1$, $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$, with $x=1/z$.

Comment: Aha! Excellent. Thank you. Please do write this up as an answer so I can reward you properly :)